# Unit Test could not pass due to constructur error

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, java-8

I am struggling at wrting unit test, when I test my code block, it says : constructor error

my code below;

```
@Component
public class CodeConfigBuilder {

    @Value("${promoConfig.prefix.length}")
    private Integer prefixLength;


    public void validateRequestAndSetDefaults(PromoRequest promoRequest) {

        prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength(promoRequest);
}

   

     private void prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength(PromoRequest promoRequest) {
        
                if (promoRequest.getPostfix() != null) {
        
                    int lengthControl = prefixLength + promoRequest.getPostfix().length();
        
                    if (lengthControl >= promoRequest.getLength()) {
        
                        throw new BadRequestException(Constant.ClientConstants.THE_SUM_OF_PREFIX_AND_POSTFIX_CAN_NOT_BE_GREATER_THAN_LENGHT);
                    }
                }
        
            }
    
    public void validateRequestAndSetDefaults(PromoRequest promoRequest) { 
      
    prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength(PromoRequest promoRequest)
    
    }



 my yml configuration below;


 #=========  Promo  Config  ========== #
    
        promoConfig:
          prefix:
            length: 3
```

my service below;

```
public void validateRequest(PromoRequest promoRequest) {
      
        codeConfigBuilder.validateRequestAndSetDefaults(promoRequest);
    }
```

I have a created PropertySourceResolver class

```
  @Value("${promoGenerationConfig.prefix.length}")
        private Integer prefixLength;
```

and my test class below;

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class CodeConfigBuilderTest {

    private final PromonRequest promoRequest;
    private final PropertySourceResolver propertySourceResolver;
    private final PromoService promoService;
    private final Request request;

    public CodeConfigBuilderTest(PromonRequest promoGenerationRequest, PropertySourceResolver propertySourceResolver, PromoService promoService, Request request) {
        this.PromonRequest = PromonRequest ;
        this.propertySourceResolver = propertySourceResolver;
        this.promoService = promoService;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Test
    void prefixAndPostFixControlAccordingToLength() {

        promoService.validateRequest(promoRequest);

        int lengthControl = propertySourceResolver.getPrefixLength() + promoRequest.getPostfix().length();

        Assertions.assertTrue(true, String.valueOf(lengthControl));

    }
```

I have tried many things but my code does not pass the test it says "org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter"

any help, thank you

Comment: Consider showing the code of the unit test that is failing.

Comment: Thank you for your replay I have edited below

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% but IMHO you can't use constructor injection in unit tests.

Use this instead:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CodeConfigBuilderTest {

    @Autowired
    private PromonRequest promoRequest;
    @Autowired
    private PropertySourceResolver propertySourceResolver;
    @Autowired
    private PromoService promoService;
    @Autowired
    private Request request;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think I could not write a proper unit test, would you kindly correct my code, thank you

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: I need to write a proper unit test that according to my scenario below; prefix and postfix can not be greater than length

Comment: @markwhalf well SimonMartinelli answered your question, I think the rest you can do write-and-change